# SVG rotate attribute of the <animateMotion> element set to auto not working correctly

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-animate

I have a question to svg animation. Please find my code [here](https://codepen.io/lkubinski/pen/vzRoPV). Using javascript I am adding *animateMotion* element to red arrow symbol. I would like to achieve the following thing

- Arrow should move on the path designated by rectangle and rotate to align with the slope of the path (so rotate 90 deg)

I can partially meet this requirement. Moving arrow along the given path is quite simple. JS script is setting path attribute for animateMotion element. I wanted to use rotate attribute to fit rotate changes to the path.
Please have a look that when you uncomment this line

> animateMotion.setAttribute("rotate", "auto");

in JS code something strange happens. Instead rotating 90 deg after reaching each corner arrow unexpected disappear. 
Do you know why?

Thank you very much in advance.

```js
class Point {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

function getArrowSymbolXcoordinate(pathAttribute) {
  var commaIdx = pathAttribute.indexOf(',');
  return pathAttribute.substring(1,commaIdx);
}

function getArrowSymbolYcoordinate(pathAttribute) {
  var commaIdx = pathAttribute.indexOf(',');
  var lineCommandIdx = pathAttribute.indexOf('l');
  console.log(pathAttribute.substring(commaIdx, lineCommandIdx));
  return pathAttribute.substring(commaIdx+1, lineCommandIdx);
}


function getTopPathAttribute(element, xCoordinate) {
  var toTopRightCorrner = Math.abs(topRightCorrner.x - xCoordinate);
  var path = 'm0,0 ' + 'h' + toTopRightCorrner + ' v' + height + ' h-' + width + ' v-' + height + ' z';
  return path;
}


let topLeftCorrner = new Point(200,100);
let topRightCorrner = new Point(350,100);
let bottomLeftCorrner = new Point(200,150);
let bottomRightCorrner = new Point(350,150);

let topArrowSymbols = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('top'));

let width = Math.abs(topLeftCorrner.x - topRightCorrner.x);
let height = Math.abs(topLeftCorrner.y - bottomLeftCorrner.y);

topArrowSymbols.forEach( function(element) {
  var xCoordinate = getArrowSymbolXcoordinate(element.getAttribute('d'));
  var animateMotion = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "animateMotion");
  var pathAttribute = getTopPathAttribute(element, xCoordinate);
  animateMotion.setAttribute("dur", "7s");
  animateMotion.setAttribute("path", pathAttribute);
  //animateMotion.setAttribute("rotate", 'auto');
  element.appendChild(animateMotion);
});
```

```css
body {
 height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <script src="main_home.js" defer="defer"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <figure >
  
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="120 80 300 200">
        <g>
            <rect fill="none" height="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" width="150" x="200" y="100"/>
            <path class="arrow_symbol top" d="m215.21876,99.72372l-2.49741,-2.5l1.64474,0l2.49741,2.5l-2.49741,2.5l-1.64474,0l2.49741,-2.5z" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="2"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</figure>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please refer to my answer to your other question: [SVG animation - rotation and transformation problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52119524/svg-animation-rotation-and-transformation-problem#52121547)

Comment: @enxaneta Thank you for a quick response. The problem is that I do not see difference between your's example and what I am doing here. Am I missing something? I am also using rotate attribute but somehow it is not working as expected. Can you please refer to my JS code and tell me what is wrong there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your arrow has a large offset from the origin of the SVG. So when it hits the end of the first curve and rotates around the corner, it is disappearing off screen.

Here is a simplified example that hopefully shows what is happening.

```html
<svg viewbox="-100 -100 400 400" width="400">

  <!-- axes to show the origin -->
  <line x1="0" y1="-100" x2="0" y2="300" stroke="#cce" stroke-width="1"/>
  <line x1="-100" y1="0" x2="300" y2="0" stroke="#cce" stroke-width="1"/>
  
  <!-- the path that the arrow is actually following (ie the one in the animateMotion) -->
  <rect width="80" height="80" fill="none" stroke="#888" stroke-width="2"/>

  <!-- dashed line showing the offset from the animateMotionPath to the arrow -->
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100" fill="none" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="10 10">
    <animateMotion dur="7s" rotate="auto"
                   path="M 0,0 L 80,0 L 80,80 L 0,80 Z"/>
  </line>

  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

  <!-- the pon-screen path that the arrow appears to be following -->
  <rect fill="none" x="100" y="100" width="80" height="80" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />

  <!-- the arrow -->
  <path class="arrow_symbol top" d="M 110,100 L 100,110 L 100,90 Z" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="2">
    <animateMotion dur="7s" rotate="auto"
                   path="M 0,0 L 80,0 L 80,80 L 0,80 Z"/>
  </path>

</svg>
```

To fix your SVG, you have to make sure that your arrow rotates around its centre. Not the origin.

```js
let topArrowSymbols = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('top'));

topArrowSymbols.forEach( function(element) {
  var animateMotion = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "animateMotion");
  animateMotion.setAttribute("dur", "7s");
  animateMotion.setAttribute("path", 'm 220,100 h 130 v 50 h -150 v -50 z');
  animateMotion.setAttribute("rotate", 'auto');
  animateMotion.setAttribute("fill", "freeze");
  element.appendChild(animateMotion);
});
```

```css
body {
 height: 100vh;
}

svg {
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  left: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <script src="main_home.js" defer="defer"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <figure >
  
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="120 80 300 200">
        <g>
            <rect id="my-path" fill="none" height="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" width="150" x="200" y="100"/>
            <path class="arrow_symbol top" d="m0.21876,0.72372l-2.49741,-2.5l1.64474,0l2.49741,2.5l-2.49741,2.5l-1.64474,0l2.49741,-2.5z" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="2"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</figure>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Paul LeBeau - This is answer that I was looking for. Thank you very much